# SQL percentage of rows comparing two dates

Tags: sql, db2

I have table `INCIDENT` with rows

```
TICKETID   ACTUALFINISH          TARGETFINISH
100      2012-03-01 11:11:11    2012-02-01 11:11:11 
101      2012-03-01 11:11:11    2012-01-01 11:11:11 
102      2012-04-01 11:11:11    2012-06-01 11:11:11 
103      2012-05-01 11:11:11    2012-07-01 11:11:11 
104        null                        null
```

I want to have in percentage of rows where `target finish` is bigger than `actual finish` and opposite.

So for this table result will be (not involving null values):

```
SLA    PERCENTAGE
YES    50
NO     50
```

I wrote SQL query but I keep getting an error. I do not know where is the error.

I first getting total number of records than where AFis bigger than TF and then AF is smaller than TF

```
with HELPTABLE as
    (select count(*) as Total

from incident as incident4

where incident4.targetfinish is not null and incident4.actualfinish is not null )


select distinct  case when incident.targetfinish>incident.actualfinish  then 
                dec((( select count(*)

 from incident as incident1

 where  incident1.targetfinish is not null and incident1.actualfinish is not null  )),10,2)/HELPTABLE.Total*100

 when incident.targetfinish<incident.actualfinish  then 

                dec(((select count(*)

from incident as incident2

where incident2.targetfinish is not null and incident2.actualfinish is not null  )),10,2)/HELPTABLE.Total*100
                    end as Percentage,

        case when incident.targetfinish>incident.actualfinish then 'Yes'
             when incident.targetfinish<incident.actualfinish then 'No'
        end as SLA



from incident

where  incident.targetfinish is not null and incident.actualfinish is not null
```

If someone knows what is the error thanks!

> [Error Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206,
>   SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=HELPTABLE.TOTAL, DRIVER=3.57.82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'YES' as SLA, 
(SUM(case when targetfinish > actualfinish  then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(*) ) * 100 as PERCENTAGE 
from incident 
where targetfinish is not null and actualfinish is not null
union 
select 'NO' as SLA, 
(SUM(case when targetfinish <= actualfinish  then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(*) ) * 100 as PERCENTAGE 
from incident
where targetfinish is not null and actualfinish is not null
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e903/18

Comment: Thanks, but I keep getting 0 return for this value. I tried with only select 'YES' as SLA, 
(SUM(case when targetfinish > actualfinish  then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) ) * 100 as PERCENTAGE 
from incident
where targetfinish is not null and actualfinish is not null  and I am getting 0 for return?

Comment: @Dejan right, I edited : put 1.0 (and 0,0) or cast one part of the division as float will do the trick. If you don't, it's an integer division, and in integer, 2 / 5 = 0